# Android sound file replaced with new wav file , but plays old wav file

Tags: android, wav

I have application with a wav sound file which was working fine now i replaced with another sound wav file but still it plays old wav file. i tried , uninstalling/installing  and deleted the old file from eclipse project folder but not luck.
Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project?